# Inserting geometry in ArcSDE table?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, postgresql-9.5

I have a test point table that created via ArcMap create feature class tool. And I am using ArcGIS 10.5 and PostgreSQL 9.5 database. I am using PG_GEOMETRY.

I want to insert a sample point using sql query.

```
insert into 
      sde.test 
values(
      sde.next_rowid('sde', 'test'), 
      'sample', 
      st_asbinary(ST_Point('POINT (52 24)', 4326))
);
```

but this query inserted a NULL geometry in my test table.

To insert data using an SQL query, should I update any other tables after the insert?

I have selected table info like this:

```
SELECT table_schema ,column_name ,data_type ,udt_schema ,udt_name ,numeric_precision ,numeric_precision_radix ,numeric_scale ,character_maximum_length FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'test';
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your table description? I think you might have a data type issue. Do a `SELECT 
 table_schema
 ,column_name
 ,data_type
 ,udt_schema
 ,udt_name
 ,numeric_precision
 ,numeric_precision_radix
 ,numeric_scale
 ,character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'test';` and update your question.

Comment: Does it have to be by SQL query? For an ArcSDE base I'd use an InsertCursor: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm

Comment: @JayCummins I have updated the post.

Comment: Do not **ever** load data into tables owned by the `sde` user/schema. Doing so greatly increases the chance of corrupting or destroying your geodatabase. Best practice is to create muliple logins and group roles, and to manage data without ever using the `sde` user directly. The SQL you have provided would insert a BLOB, not a geometry. Please [Edit] the question to specify which type of geometry you want to create (PostGIS or sde.st_geometry).